# How to convert a character column with a specific date format into date without having some values turn into NAs?

Tags: r, date, character

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Date_1 (char)   Date_2 (char)
Jul 10, 2019    Jul 13, 2019
Sep 10, 2018    Dec 14, 2018
Oct 25, 2021    Nov 14, 2022
...
```

I have not found a fitting code yet to convert these two character columns into type date. Output should be something like `'mm/dd/yyyy'`. Grateful for any tips.

EDIT:
Here is my dput

`structure(list(Start_Date = c("Dec 12, 2017", "Oct 19, 2022","Oct 3, 2022"), End_Date = c("Dec 25, 2017", "Dec 19, 2022",  "Dec 1, 2022"), Completion = c("100% completed", "34% completed",  "62% completed")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Maels answer works for some values but others are just turned into NAs - see dput in comment section.

Comment: `library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, across(, mdy))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps.

1. First convert to a date object. You can use `as.Date` and you have to specify how the date is formatted in the first place.
2. Then you can format it as you like. You should use the `format` function.

This might a bit confusing since `format` is used twice for different purposes.

```r
Date_1 = "Jul 10, 2019"
as.Date(Date_1, format = "%b %d, %Y") |>
  format("%m-%d-%Y")
#[1] "07-10-2019"
```

---

Edit, in base R, using your `dput`:

```r
data <- structure(list(Start_Date = c("Dec 12, 2017", "Oct 19, 2022","Oct 3, 2022"), End_Date = c("Dec 25, 2017", "Dec 19, 2022",  "Dec 1, 2022"), Completion = c("100% completed", "34% completed",  "62% completed")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))

data[c("Start_Date", "End_Date")] <- 
  sapply(data[c("Start_Date", "End_Date")],
         function(x) as.Date(x, format = "%b %d, %Y") |>
           format("%m-%d-%Y"))
```

Comment: Still does not work unfortunately - I added my ```dput``` in the description, does that help?

Comment: Check edit. It does

Comment: @Soph2010 I guess you'll need to adapt the code your variable names :-) I.e. `data |> transform(Start_Date = as.Date(Start_Date, format = "%b %d, %Y") |> format("%m-%d-%Y"))`

Comment: I did that already ;) However, the column still looks the same...

Comment: If I use the base R code, the column turns out partly empty - partly it works

Comment: This is the output dput: structure(list(Start_Date = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), End_Date = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Completion = c("100% completed", 
"34% completed", "62% completed", NA, "47% completed")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Restart your session and clear your object list. Try the code of the answer, including the data part. If that still does not work, then I don't know what is the problem

Comment: It still only converts some of the values correctly and replaces the rest with NAs...

Comment: @Mael I figured it out - my system language was set to German so R could not identify some of the dates! Now your code works well - thank you for your help and patience!